Should nested modules with shared weights be an nn.Module object parameter or not?
I would like two torch.nn.Module classes to share part of their architecture and weights, as in the example below:
from torch import nn

class SharedBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.block = nn.Sequential(
            # Define some block architecture here...
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.block(x)

class MyNestedModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, shared_block: nn.Module, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.linear = nn.Linear(...)
        self.shared_block = shared_block

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.shared_block(self.linear(x))

class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        
        # SHOULD THIS BE:
        shared_block = SharedBlock(*args, **kwargs)
        # OR:
        self.shared_block = SharedBlock(*args, **kwargs)  # Note: self.
        # ...AND WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE, IF ANY?


        self.nested1 = MyNestedModule(shared_block, *args, **kwargs)
        self.nested2 = MyNestedModule(shared_block, *args, **kwargs)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_1, x_2 = torch.split(x, x.shape[0] // 2, dim=0)
        y_1 = self.nested1(x_1)
        y_2 = self.nested2(y_2)
        return y_1, y_2

I would like to know whether shared_block should be an object parameter of MyModule. I assume it does not, since it is set as an object parameter in both the MyNestedModule class objects so it should be registered in torch grad but if I did create it as an object parameter in MyModule what would happen?

It doesn't matter, the parameters are tracked both ways. If you use shared_block = ..., the parameters in shared_block will be referenced in your state dict (model.state_dict()) twice, once for self.nested1 and again for self.nested2.
If you use the self.shared_block = ... approach, the state dict will reference the parameters a third time in MyModule itself.
Either way, the parameters are tracked and model.parameters() will return a non-duplicated set of parameters.
You can run this code to look at a simplified version
import torch
from torch import nn

class SharedBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.block = nn.Linear(8, 8)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.block(x)

class MyNestedModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, shared_block):
        super().__init__()

        self.shared_block = shared_block

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.shared_block(x)
    
class MyModule1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        shared_block = SharedBlock()

        self.nested1 = MyNestedModule(shared_block)
        self.nested2 = MyNestedModule(shared_block)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_1, x_2 = torch.split(x, x.shape[0] // 2, dim=0)
        y_1 = self.nested1(x_1)
        y_2 = self.nested2(x_2)
        return y_1, y_2
    
class MyModule2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shared_block = SharedBlock()

        self.nested1 = MyNestedModule(self.shared_block)
        self.nested2 = MyNestedModule(self.shared_block)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_1, x_2 = torch.split(x, x.shape[0] // 2, dim=0)
        y_1 = self.nested1(x_1)
        y_2 = self.nested2(x_2)
        return y_1, y_2
    
    
model1 = MyModule1()
print(model1.state_dict())
print(list(model1.parameters()))

model2 = MyModule2()
print(model2.state_dict())
print(list(model2.parameters()))

